# Adapt Pascal function AnsiChar() and AnsiString() in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion, pascal, ansistring

i need to adapt a pascal script into JavaScript.
I was able to translate nearly all the code except this two functions.

Pascal codelines:

```
Result:= AnsiChar(b + ord('0'));

s:= AnsiString(copy(ReNr, 1, length(ReNr) - 1));`
```

The code in the AnsiChar()-function i already adapt with `'0'.codePointAt(0) % 10`, and the code in the AnsiString() with `ReNr.substr(1, ReNr.length - 1)`. But i don't understand what the Pascal Ansi-functions does.

**Is there a JavaScript pendant to Pascals `AnsiChar()` and `AnsiString()` functions or what i have to do, to get the same effect in JavaScript?**

Comment: `AnsiChar` and `AnsiString` seem to be datatypes. https://wiki.freepascal.org/Character_and_string_types

Comment: also I think it should be `ReNr.substr(0, ReNr.length - 1)` javascript `substr()` is zero-based while pascal `copy` is one-based https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/copy.html

Comment: @GrafiCode in the script they are used like functions, so it seems like its a type constructor? If it is a constructor and the character or string inside are getting converted into Ansi, is there a possibility to adapt this behaviour in JS? And thank you very much for the hint of the zero based function. One issue less for later debugging.

Comment: yes I believe it has something to do with type casting, but I don't really know how to apply this in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I belive it will be something like this:

```
Result = String.fromCharCode(b + '0'.charCodeAt(0) );

S = ReNr.substring(0, ReNr.length - 2);
```

Delphi's AnsiChar() creates a character from a given ASCII code.

AnsiString converts string to Ansi encoding if it was in multibyte.